# BOTON DE CERRAR UNIVERSAL

Tags: c#

estoy creando un formulario de menú personalizado y necesito tener un único botón de cerrar, para cerrar cualquier formulario que se muestre en el Panel Contenedor. El código para mostrar los formularios en el Panel es lo siguiente:

```
    //METODO PARA ABRIR FORM DENTRO DEL PANEL
    private void AbrirFormEnPanel(object formContenedor)
    {
        if (PanelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            PanelContenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        Form formHijo = formContenedor as Form;
        formHijo.TopLevel = false;
        formHijo.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        formHijo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(formHijo);
        PanelContenedor.Tag = formHijo;
        formHijo.Show();
    }
```

Ahora necesito un botón para cerrar los formularios abiertos dentro del Panel. Si por favor puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Comment: puedes intentar recorriendo PanelContenedor.Controls y vas cerrandolos como se hayan agregado

Comment: he encontrado la solución, a través de un simple condición. if (PanelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            PanelContenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        }